# Why does Eclipse not deploy dependency to Glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, glassfish, java-ee-6

I am using Eclipse Helios, Glassfish 3.0.1 (Full Platform) and myfaces 2.0 .

There a two projects in the workspace: A simple Java project (=> JP) and a dynamic web project (=> WP). I added JP to the classpath of WP.

I added one class from JP as a managed bean to the faces-config.xml file of WP.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>myPackage.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

When I deploy the package and make a request, an error message is displayed. It says, that the myPackage.MyBean class could not be found.

If I look into WEB-INF/classes directory, of the deployed and running WP project, this directory is empty.

I did not wrote any classes inside WP itself yet, **but shouldn't be the classes of JP in that directory?**

**What can I do to deploy JP together with WP?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the plain Java Project as a module/deployment dependency. In the current Eclipse version (Helios, 3.6) you can do it in *Deployment Assembly* of the project's properties. In the older versions (Galileo, 3.5 and before) you can do it in *Java EE Module Dependencies* of the project's properties. It will then end up as a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Failing the eclipse tie-in of "Module Dependencies" (or if it all seems complicated) then manually jar the class files of project JP (e.g. as jp.jar) and add the jar to WEB/INF/lib of project WP

this will fix your ClassNotFoundException