# JAR libraries in WEB-INF/lib not added to classpath during Glassfish deployment

Tags: deployment, classpath, war, glassfish-3

I'm new to Glassfish and Java EE although I've been using Java for a few years. I've inherited a project that stalled and now I need to start development on it again. I'm trying to deploy the web application as-is to see what works and what needs attention. While there is a lot of code to implement various functions, it appears that the first point needing attention is deployment of the application.

The web application I'm trying to deploy is `MyServer` and is packaged in a WAR archive. A class in `MyServer` has a reference to a class in `MyDatabase` which implements an interface (`InterfaceOne`) from `MyInterfaces`. The class in `MyServer` also has a direct reference to `InterfaceOne` from `MyInterfaces`. `MyServer`, `MyDatabase` and `MyInterfaces` are all projects in Eclipse and packaged using Maven. The `MyServer` POM file lists `MyDatabase` as a dependency and the POM file for `MyDatabase` lists `MyInterfaces` as a dependency. The `MyServer` POM file doesn't list `MyInterfaces` as an immediate dependency but I don't think that this should cause an issue. Eclipse doesn't show any errors in the `MyServer` class concerned; Eclipse appears to consider the Maven dependencies to be sufficient to locate all necessary classes.

When I deploy the `MyServer` WAR on Glassfish v3.1.2 via the Admin web console and then view the logs in `~glassfish3/glassfish/domains/MyDomain/logs/server.log` I encounter the following errors:

> [#|2014-05-29T10:06:02.371+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=80;_ThreadName=Thread-2;| Class [ my/interfaces/InterfaceOne] not found. Error while loading [ class my.server.ControllerOne ]|#]
>   [#|2014-05-29T10:06:02.387+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=80;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ my/interfaces/InterfaceOne ] not found. Error while loading [ class my.server.ControllerOne ]|#]

There are two errors shown relating to the interface while trying to load the class from `MyServer`. If I remove either the reference to `MyDatabase` or the direct reference to `InterfaceOne` from `MyInterfaces` from the `my.server.ControllerOne` class then one of the errors above disappears (which is expected and just confirms that the error is related to the references (directly and indirectly) of the `InterfaceOne` from `MyInterfaces`.

Similar questions including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782109), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044350) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560943) all mention ensuring that the required libraries (`my-database.jar` and `my-interfaces.jar`) are located in the `WEB-INT/lib` directory of the `MyServer` application's WAR archive. However, if I inspect the generated WAR archive for `MyServer` then the libraries are indeed located in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory. If I inspect the `~glassfish3/glassfish/domains/MyDomain/applications/MyServer/WEB-INF/lib/` directory after deployment the libraries are there too. I assume this indicates that they were successfully extracted from the WAR archive and placed on the Glassfish server. The point is the libraries are definitely there!

All I can think of is that the libraries are not added to classpath of the JVM trying to load the classes of `MyServer` but surely if Glassfish tries to load classes of an application then it should also first load the libraries packaged with the application shouldn't it? Indeed [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/class-loaders.htm) page from the Oracle GlassFish Server Application Development Guide
Release 3.1.2 indicates that the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory of an application is added to the application's classpath.

I've seen other suggestions that libraries required by web applications be placed in the `~glassfish3/glassfish/domains/MyDomain/lib/ext/` directory. That might very well work but my specific libraries are required by the `MyServer` application only, not the whole of `MyDomain`. As far as I can tell, it should be valid to place them in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory of my application.

Does anyone have any ideas about why the `my-database.jar` and `my-interfaces.jar` libraries don't seem to be added to the classpath during deployment? More specifically, does anyone know why the `my.interfaces.InterfaceOne` class isn't visible while loading the `my.server.ControllerOne` class during deployment?

`MyServer`'s `web.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyServer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/balusc.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

MyServer pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Server</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </parent>
    <organization>
        <name>Example</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    </organization>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eclipselink</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>utilities</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-database</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <configuration> section added to pick up the WEB-INF/web.xml inside
                    WebContent -->
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_server</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_server/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>
</project>
```

MyDatabase pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>my-database</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eclipselink</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcrypt</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-interfaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_database</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_database/trunk/</developerConnection>
  </scm>
  <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
</project>
```

MyInterfaces pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-interfaces</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
      <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-parent-pom</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>

  </parent>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_interfaces</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.server/location/in/repo/my_interfaces/trunk</developerConnection>
  </scm>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.webapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-utilities</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
        <classifier>me</classifier>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `MyInterfaces` POM lists a dependency on `MyUtilities`. I think this can be safely ignored for this question since none of it's classes appear in the error messages I've described. It is also placed in the `WEB-INT/lib/` directory on the Glassfish server when my application is deployed.

(Glassfish questions appear to require a lot of info like web.xml files and pom.xml etc. Thanks for taking the time to sift through all of this.)

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: Is there something specific in the POMs you are looking for? Since the libraries are placed in the WEB-INF/lib directory on the Glassfish server during deployment I don't know what it is in the POMs that may help resolve this. Of course, that may be why I'm having this problem in the first place...

Comment: Nothing specific, it just makes it easier to understand the packaging. Is the `utilities` dependency in the my-server-pom.xml the same as the `my-utilities` dependency in my-interfaces-pom.xml? It may cause that the wrong version of `my-utilities` is packaged in the webapp.

Comment: No, they're not the same. They just have similar names to keep me on my toes.

Comment: Strange stuff, I have setup a basic project with the same structure and it works. I noticed that the error message one time mentions `my/interface` and one time `my/interfaces`. Is this correct or some kind of typo?

Comment: That was a typo, I've fixed it now. From what I've been able to find, the whole point of the WEB-INF/lib/ directory is to make application specific libraries available to the application.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Is the my-utilities.jar in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: yip, all the libraries are there. The issue is that the classes they contain aren't visible when the MyServer classes are loaded during deployment. Glassfish has separate Deploy and Launch actions. I'd expect Deploy to upload, extract the WAR and register anything that needs to be registered. I'd expect the Launch action to actually load classes and start processes. Why are classes being loaded when I deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there were two issues at play:

1. Firstly `MyServer's` `web.xml` `<display-name>` was incorrect. This
   wasn't visible in my question because I'd changed the library names
   (which contain client names). Part of the requirements given to me
   for the project were to rebrand the project and I missed the
   `<display-name>` element. Oops.
2. The second issue was that, while
   investigating this issue, I moved the `MyDatabase` and
   `MyInterfaces` libraries from the `MyServer` `WEB-INF/lib/`
   directory to the domain's `lib/ext/` directory and back. This
   changed the errors logged during deployment (since the libraries
   were visible despite the incorrect `<display-name>` but they errors
   didn't reappear when I moved the database and interface libraries
   back into the `MyServer` application. I think Glassfish was caching
   the libraries and not updating the cached libraries during
   deployment. Stopping/starting the domain updated the cache.

To summarise, once the `<display-name>` of MyServer was changed and the Glassfish library cache was updated, the class loading errors appear resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a project with basically the same structure as you described and I can't reproduce the problem nor do I have an additional idea what could be wrong.

Therefore I have pushed my test project to GitHub so you can try it and maybe you find any hint what is different in your project.

The project is here: https://github.com/erdbeerschnitzel/war-packaging

If you don't have a GitHub account to clone the project you can download the ZIP (button on the lower right). Extract it somewhere and load the 5 projects in your IDE, build everything and deploy the WAR file of the **my-server** project.

I left out the parent project and removed some dependencies like eclipselink and primefaces but I think that shouldn't make the difference.

Good luck.

Update:

> Glassfish has separate Deploy and Launch actions. I'd expect Deploy to
>   upload, extract the WAR and register anything that needs to be
>   registered. I'd expect the Launch action to actually load classes and
>   start processes. Why are classes being loaded when I deploy?

Actually the application (and therefore the classes) is loaded when you deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for the sample project. I'll update here if I ever find the cause.